# Qu'est-ce que ça signifie « Zéro tracas, zéro blabla » ?

Tags: sens

C'est le slogan d'une assurance… Surtout je n'arrive pas à comprendre ce que signifie « tracas ».

Comment: -1 pour l'avoir rappelé à la mémoire de chacun. (Et *tracas* est dans n'importe quel dictionnaire.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Un [tracas](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tracas) (invariable), est un souci, un ennui. Par ce slogan cette assurance dit qu'elle fait tout pour vous (vous n'avez pas de tracas) et que ce qu'elle dit est transparent, qu'elle ne cherche pas à tromper les gens (elle ne fait pas de [blabla](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/blabla)).

Comment: Et on peut observer également que le registre choisi, l'indigence extrême du message, et la répétition ad nauseam de ce navrant mantra donnent une idée assez édifiante du profond mépris qu'ont ces gens pour les destinataires de leur propagande. Sur la forme, c'est même un mensonge auto-référentiel, équivalent à « *Je ne suis pas en train de vous parler.* » ou « *Ceci n'est pas une phrase.* »